# How to write the type for a boxed closure which takes a reference as an argument and returns an object which references data from the argument?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to define the following type in Rust:

```rust
type JsTaskCallback = Box<
    dyn (FnOnce(&'a mut RuntimeHandle<'a>) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = anyhow::Result<()>> + 'a>>)
        + Send,
>;
```

It is intended to allow the user to pass in a closure which accepts a `RuntimeHandle` (a struct that I defined which lives for `'a`) and returns a future which lives for at least as long as the `RuntimeHandle` reference (necessary in order for the code calling this function to `await` the returned future).

**Where should I specify `'a`?** Specifying it on `JsTaskCallback` would not be correct, because the lifetime in use is defined at the call site. Specifying `'_` is not correct, because there are too many lifetimes for the compiler to infer anything. And leaving out the lifetime inside the `Pin<Box>` is not correct, because I don't want to force the returned future to be `'static`.

While researching this, I discovered the Rustnomicon page on [HRTBs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), but I'm not sure how to apply the information in there to trait objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. You need to use HRTB. The syntax is like:

```rust
type JsTaskCallback = Box<
    dyn (for<'a> FnOnce(
            &'a mut RuntimeHandle<'a>,
        ) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = anyhow::Result<()>> + 'a>>)
        + Send,
>;
```

It means "for any lifetime `'a` the function will be called with, with an argument of type `&'a mut RuntimeHandle<'a>`, it will return a future living for `'a`".